# Trouble with adding fractions in MIPS assembly language (Seg Fault)

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am still very new to MIPS assembly language programming and am having some trouble. I have been tasked to create a Add function in MIPS assembly language that takes one ration number ($a0, $a1) and adds it to ($a2, $a3) using the rules of rational arithmetic. I am getting a seg fault and not sure why. This is what I currently have

```
rat_add:

addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # create space on the stack for $sp 
sw    $ra, ($sp)    # save $sp on the stack

sw $t0, ($a1)     # Storing value in $a1(denominator of the first) into $t0
sw $t1, ($a3)     # Storing value in $a3(denominator of the second) into $t1

mul $a0, $a0, $t1 # $a0 *= $t1
mul $a1, $a1, $t1 # $a1 *= $t1

mul $a2, $a2, $t0 # $a2 *= $t0
mul $a3, $a3, $t0 # $a3 *= $t0  

add $v0, $a0, $a2 # $v0 = $a0 + $a2
add $v1, $0, $a3  # Both denominators are the same, don't need to add them

lw    $ra, ($sp)    # restore $sp from the stack 
addiu $sp, $sp, +4  # release the stack space used for $sp

jr $ra
```

I am not sure why I am getting this seg fault when I try to run the program. I am guessing it is coming from the stack pointer, but I did the samething for multiply and divide with not trouble. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. To better illustrate what I am try to do is 1/2 + 2/7 = 11/14

Comment: Use `move $t0, $a1` instead of `sw $t0, ($a1)`.

Comment: Thanks @markgz that solved the problem. So move is like add, I could of just said add $t0, $0, $a1 to move that value to $t0. I think I had my register backwards as well for the sw instruction. Should been sw $a1, ($t0). I guess the confusion comes from the fact that in MIPS assembly syntax normally the destination operand is the left (most) one.
This is not the case in the sw instruction:
In the sw instruction the left operand register is stored to the memory address based on the right operand register.

Comment: @TurtleMan: `move` probably does actually assemble to something like add-with-the-zero-register.  MIPS machine code doesn't have a separate `move` opcode, because it doesn't need one.  `move` is just a human-friendly synonym, also called a pseudo-op.  If you assembled, and then disassembled the resulting binary, you'd see what actually happened.  (Unless you use a "smart" disassembler that turns idioms like add-with-$0 back into the human-friendly `move`.)

Comment: And yeah, I always find it weird dealing with RISC machines that put the address in the same operand for both load and store instructions, instead of putting the memory destination on the usual destination side the way x86 assembly language does.  If it helps, think of it this way: neither register is being written by a store instruction.  It has to read both registers, and use one as an address and the other as data.  There is no register destination.  I don't think that helps much or justifies the syntax, though :/